# Vb.net insert row statement executed twice

Tags: sql, vb.net, sqlcommand

In my vb.net application, I need to BackUp some data from one table to another. Here is my code

```
con2.Open()
txt2 = "select * from pension where empno='" & empno & "' ORDER BY year"
cmd2 = New SqlCommand(txt2, con2)
reader2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader()
While reader2.Read
    yr = reader2("year")
    totpension = reader2("total")
    If dr <> yr Then
        dcrg = 0
        comm = 0
    End If
    tot1 = dcrg + comm + totpension
    con3.Open()
    txt1 = "Insert into over1 values('" & empno & "','" & name & "','" & yr & "','" & dcrg & "', '" & comm & "','" & totpension & "','" & tot1 & "')"
    cmd3 = New SqlCommand(txt1, con3)
    cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con3.Close()
End While
reader2.Close()
con2.Close()
```

The problem is it inserts every record twice, I removed ORDER BY, also the same problem continues. Using parameterized queries also having the same problem.

Can someone explain what is the problem in my code and how to solve it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are trying to insert the rows from the table `pension` into the table `over1`, use `INSERT INTO over1 SELECT * FROM pension where ...` directly without the need of the while loop.

Comment: Based on the value for `txt1`, it doesn't look like OP is trying to insert a record from one table into another.

Comment: If you execute this code multiple times, there will be duplicate records in pension table. Do you have constraints added to pensions table, that will prevent duplicate entry for (empno + year) combination? Alternatively, delete records from pensions table for (empno + year) combination, followed by inserts.

Comment: This looks like the kind of thing that could all be done as a single `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement on the server, rather than processing each row individually in the client.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple Things,
If you have single record of each employee in pension table then

use `if reader2.Read` instead of `while reader2.Read`

If the problem persists Then the problem is you are executing this method twice. Question is How?

1. If it is a method. Then you may be calling this method twice

   ---
2. If it is an event then may be you are handling this event twice 
       So, Check the control tag from which the event is fired that this event is called there. like this

   ```
   <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click"/>
   ```

   and also check the event's `Handled` property

   ```
   Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As StartEventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
   ```

   If you defined `OnClick` attribute you must remove `Handles btnSubmit.Click` from event.

Hope this will help.